# Django Rest Framework не понимает django.core.exceptions.ValidationError

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Я использую Django Rest Framework.
Предположим, у меня есть следующая модель:

```
class Product:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    url = URLField()
```

И соответствующие ей `ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)` и `ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet)`

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы связка `owner` и `url` были уникальными и на фронтенд возвращался json с ошибкой в случае повторного добавления продукта тем же `owner` и с тем же `url`.

Когда я делаю это через джанговский `unique_together`, django выбрасывает исключение `ValidationError`, которое Rest Framework не обрабатывает и выдает саму страницу исключения. Хотя, когда в поле `url` (у которого, напомню, тип URLField со встроенной джанговской валидацией) приходит некорректный url, то Rest Framework эту ситуацию обрабатывает корректно и выдает следующий json:

```
{
    "url": [
        "Enter a valid URL."
    ]
}
```

Хотелось бы узнать, если есть ли решение этой проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Я решил проблему топорно, написав свою реализацию `exception_handler` для rest framework, где проверяю тип исключения и вручную формирую ответ, если это `ValidationError`:

```
def django_exception_handler(exc, context):
    if isinstance(exc, ValidationError):
        data = exc.message_dict
        return Response(data, status=400)
    else:
        response = exception_handler(exc, context)
        return response
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling

Но, все-таки, хотелось бы понять, почему Rest Framework поддерживает даже типы джанговский полей со встроенной валидацией, но не поддерживает такую простую вещь, как обычный `ValidationError`.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное уже поздно, но всё же отвечу.
В DRF есть [UniqueTogetherValidator](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator)

Вы можете сделать так же, как написано в доке:

```
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Product.objects.all(),
                fields=('owner', 'url')
            )
        ]
```